# How can I run a query on IDs in a string?

Tags: sql, string, select

I have a table A with this column:

```
  IDS(VARCHAR)
  1|56|23
```

I need to run this query:

```
  select TEST from TEXTS where ID in ( select IDS from A where A.ID = xxx )
```

`TEXTS.ID` is an `INTEGER`. How can I split the string A.IDS into several ints for the join?

Must work on MySQL and Oracle. SQL99 preferred.

Comment: Might help telling what database engine you use.

Comment: Must work on MySQL and Oracle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should not store data like this in a column. You should split that out into a separate table, then you would have a normal join, and not this problem.

Having said that, what you have to do is the following:

1. Convert the number to a string
2. Pad it with the `|` (your separator) character, before it, and after it (I'll tell you why below)
3. Pad the text you're looking in with the same separator, before and after
4. Do a `LIKE` on it

**This will run slow!**

Here's the SQL that does what you want (assuming all the operators and functions work in your SQL dialect, you don't say what kind of database engine this is):

```
SELECT
    TEXT   -- assuming this was misspelt?
FROM
    TEXTS  -- and this as well?
    JOIN A ON
        '|' + A.IDS + '|' LIKE '%|' + CONVERT(TEXTS.ID) + '|%'
```

The reason why you need to pad the two with the separator before and after is this: what if you're looking for the number 5? You need to ensure it wouldn't accidentally fit the `56` number, just because it contained the digit.

Basically, we will do this:

```
... '|1|56|23|' LIKE '%|56|%'
```

If there is ever only going to be 1 row in A, it might run faster if you do this (but I am not sure, you would need to measure it):

```
SELECT
    TEXT   -- assuming this was misspelt?
FROM
    TEXTS  -- and this as well?
WHERE
    (SELECT '|' + IDS + '|' FROM A) LIKE '%|' + CONVERT(TEXTS.ID) + '|%'
```

If there are many rows in your `TEXTS` table, it will be worth the effort to add code to generate the appropriate SQL by first retrieving the values from the `A` table, construct an appropriate SQL with `IN` and use that instead:

```
SELECT
    TEXT   -- assuming this was misspelt?
FROM
    TEXTS  -- and this as well?
WHERE
    ID IN (1, 56, 23)
```

This will run much faster since now it can use an index on this query.

If you had A.ID as a column, and the values as separate rows, here's how you would do the query:

```
SELECT
    TEXT   -- assuming this was misspelt?
FROM
    TEXTS  -- and this as well?
    INNER JOIN A ON TEXTS.ID = A.ID
```

This will run slightly slower than the previous one, but in the previous one you have overhead in having to first retrieve `A.IDS`, build the query, and risk producing a new execution plan that has to be compiled.

Comment: Fixed "miss-spelt", I have no idea what that is, must be a misspelling performed by a Miss.