# Advanced usage of "like" statement in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, sql-like

I am now working on the sqlite in iPhone platform and dealing with the database with some strange entities.  One of the column in this DB called type, which allows multiple values (multiple types).  The data in this column is like this:

```
1|9|20|31|999
```

The table is like:

```
ID       TYPE
------------------------
1        1|9|20|31|999
2        5|13|15|30|990
3        6|7|45|46|57
```

When the user want to select the data with the type 9, it needs select the above data because the entity contains 9. And I use the following statement to execute:

```
SELECT id
  FROM table 
 WHERE type LIKE '%' || ? || '%'
```

The problem is that the data with the type 999 and without type 9 will also be selected. Also, if the user wants to select type 1, the data with type 11, 12, 13...etc will also be selected.

I tried to use the statement:

```
SELECT id
  FROM table 
 WHERE type LIKE '[^0123456789]' || ? || '[^0123456789]'
```

But it can't select any data.

What can I do to select the data with correct type?

(The database cannot be changed because of the company requirement)

Comment: this looks like a regular expression problem. not posting as an answer because i'm not providing the expression itself. :)

Comment: p.s. - press harder for changing the database - this is horrible, you will save more in the end by doing it right in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks all of you. It has been solved by bw_üezi'answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
SELECT id
  FROM table 
 WHERE '|' + type + '|' LIKE '%|' + ? + '|%'
```

(I use the `+` operator here because it's easier to read but you could also use `||` instead)

It's an easy solution without regex. Indexes don't help anything here (this is the same for regex solution) the query will be slow with huge data.

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3838471/397667) I asked myself a while ago. Also check it's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838471/how-can-i-run-a-query-on-ids-in-a-string/3838508#3838508)

Answer (score 2):

You'd need a regular expression that matches only `'yournumber|'`, `'|yournumber|'`, `'|yournumber'`, or a combination of the above. I see no way an optimizer could use an index on that kind of thing short of a specialized index that would work similarly to full-text indexes.

This is almost hopeless, unless you have a trivial amount of data (or way too many processing resources), it will not scale.

If the amount of data is small, consider just selecting `like '%number%'`, and do some post-processing in you application code.

Otherwise, normalize you data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too much familiar with SQLite but what about:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE type REGEX '(^9\|.*)|(.*\|9\|.*)|(.*\|9$)';
```

assuming that you are looking for the type `9`

Then to look for type `999` it would be:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE type REGEX '(^999\|.*)|(.*\|999\|.*)|(.*\|999$)';
```

Note that you might want to tweak the expression if you may potentially have a single type value in the `type` field because in that case I'd suppose that there wouldn't be any `|` character.